# Best way to represent sets of 3 values

Tags: c#, generics, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Assume that I have 100 sets of 3 values. first value is time, second value is x position and 3rd value is y position. this is going to be the xy position of a point over 100 seconds for example.
I have a PHP background. in PHP I would do it with a 3D associative array like this :

```
position["time"]["x"]["y"]
```

so I can access x,y values at a certain time. How would you do this in c#? I think generics like list and dictionary would do that. but I don't know how to implement key values for a 3D set of data.

Comment: It depends on how you want to access  your data.

Comment: I would use a `List<Item>` The Item class holds those 3 values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to access an x/y position at a given time. You might consider a combination of the other answers along with a dictionary.

Define a simple struct which holds x & y positions. It is important that this object is immutable.

```
public struct Position
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Position(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

Now you can store these in a dictionary with (perhaps) `DateTime` as the key.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Position> positions = new Dictionary<DateTime, Position>();
positions.Add(new DateTime(2017,3,29,10,0,0), new Position(10,10));
```

And you can read your position like

```
var pos = positions[new DateTime(2017,3,29,10,0,0)];
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",pos.X,pos.Y);
```

---

A neat little addition to this is that if, for example, you are getting a list of these object you wish to lookup by time you can easily turn them into a dictionary. Say your get a list of these (from other answer):

```
public class PositionEntity
{
   public DateTime Time {get;set;}
   public int X {get;set;}
   public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

As a list `entities` you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<PositionEntity> entities = .... loaded from somewhere
var dict = entities.ToDictionary(k => k.Time, v => new Position(v.X,v.Y));
```

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what I need. Just a quick question. Where should I define the struct, so that all classes in my project see this struct? should that be in a separate file like classes?

Comment: @MehdiB yes, as a general rule each type should be in its own file.

Answer (score 7):

In C# there is types concept, you would need to create a concrete custom type either struct (value type )or class (reference type)

- [Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)
- [Refrence Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

You can create a new type in this case i am creating class which would be like:

```
public class Position
{
   public DateTime Time {get;set;}
   public int X {get;set;}
   public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

Now at some point you would have a instance of class position:

```
Position postion = new Position(); // object created
positon.Time = DateTime.Now;
position.X = 1;
position.Y =0;
```

and the same way you would get the values back from it :

```
DateTime time = position.Time;
int positionX = position.X;
int positionY = position.Y;
```

I would suggest to read basics of type [from MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)

and for sets part, we have Framework provided collections in C# which includes [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx),[List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used to hold multiple objects of `Position`.

Hope It helps!

Comment: I can understand the first part clearly. but for the sets part, As you mentioned I can user arrays or list. Assume that I have used one of these. how would I access the xy position of the point at time = 50 seconds?

Comment: you would filter from list or array using `Where()`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest defining an immutable type for this purpose and use a dictionary to store values since an object can be in one place at a specific time.

```
public class Position
{
    public Position(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
}
```

use it like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, Position>();

//add data in two different ways
data.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), new Position(0.1, 1));
data[TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15)] = new Position(10, 15);

//accessing data
var pos = data[TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)];

//check if data exist for specific time
if (data.ContainsKey(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15)))
{
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: The code won't compile... You need a backing field or a `private set`

Comment: @xanatos in dotnetcore you no longer need the `private set`. getters can be written from the ctor - just in case you were unaware.

Comment: @Jamiec The primary constructor that was proposed for C# 6.0 wasn't ever released... Without a private set and without a "real" field, what syntax is used?

Comment: @xanatos just a public get (`public int MyProp {get; }`) and then you can set that from the ctor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tuple` class ([See Tuple class on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Tuple.Create("time", "x", "y"); //creates a Tuple with 3 elements, aka triple
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution might be to use a Tuple, if this is suitable for your needs, e.g.

```
Example:

var tuple = Tuple.Create(someBytes, moreBytes, myString);
```

You can access the values using tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, and tuple.Item3.

You can of course also use multiple Tuples if you require this, e.g.

Example

```
var list = new List<Tuple<byte, byte, string>> {
    tuple,
    anotherTuple,
    thirdTuple,
    etc
};
```

As others have mentioned though, if you're referencing "like" data, you should create a class instead.

Comment: While tuples are great in certain circumstances, I very quickly descend to "What was in `Item2` again??". Far better to write 6 lines of code and make it obvious

Comment: I just gave example code. Please modify according to your needs.